# Leave One Group Out CV in Python

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to apply Leave One Group Out cross validation in python code by using sklearn's LeaveOneGroupOut() but I have a problem with defining the group split.

So my data is consisted of 10 dataframes that each includes data about a participant's acceleration measures while performing an activity and I want to do LOGOCV by leaving out the data from one of the 10 participants, meaning I want to use the data from one participant as a test set and the rest 9 as a training set and repeat this 10 times (as the no. of participants).

I'm using this code https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut

but I cannot understand how to correctly define the groups parameter to give me what I want.
Any help??

Comment: Well... you probably need to have 1 data frame, with an additional column for the groups.

Comment: I gathered all the participants data in one dataframe but I can't figure out how to add the groups

Comment: You know that you need to represent the data as regular arrays right? Apparently the `group` array is provided separately, for example if you have 3 instances for every participants and they are concatenated one after the other, your `group` array should be `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,...,9,9,9,10,10,10]`. Basically `group[i]` gives the group id for instance `i`.